# How to delete every record after the nth row in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

In mysql I can query `select * ... LIMIT 10, 30` where 10 represents the number of records to skip.

Does anyone know how I can do the same thing in delete statements where every record after the first 10 records get deleted?

Comment: What is the key of your table?

Comment: This deleted answer should be mentioned I think: `DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM TABLE LIMIT 10, 30)`. @Am commented that that does not work in "this version of MySQL". So although it isn't _the_ answer to the question, it might be helpful for other answerers :)

Comment: Define "first 10".  Tables have no 'order'.  You can get order only by `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 8):

Considering there is no `rowId` in MySQL (like in Oracle), I would suggest the following:

```
alter table mytable add id int unique auto_increment not null;
```

This will automatically number your rows in the order of a `select` statement without conditions or order-by.

```
select * from mytable;
```

Then, after checking the order is consistent with your needs (and maybe a dump of the table)

```
delete from mytable where id > 10;
```

Finally, you may want to remove that field

```
alter table mytable drop id;
```

Comment: Some questions: Is it defined how adding an `auto_increment` will number when altering a table like this? Would it keep to the needed order, and if so when testing: is this "coincidence" or defined behaviour? Also: does mysql reset the `auto_increment` number after dropping the column? If not, you might want to explicitly set that, or it might keep on counting. And finally: how expencive would this become for big tables?

Comment: If `auto_increment_increment` is not 1 (in a multi-master setup), this will not work quite correctly.  Also, it will take a long time to run if the table is big.

Answer (score 4):

The following will **NOT** work:

```
DELETE 
FROM table_name 
WHERE id IN
  ( SELECT id
    FROM table_name
    ORDER BY          --- whatever
    LIMIT 10, 30
  )
```

But this will:

```
DELETE 
FROM table_name 
WHERE id IN
  ( SELECT id
    FROM 
      ( SELECT id
        FROM table_name
        ORDER BY          --- whatever
        LIMIT 10, 30
      ) AS tmp
  )
```

And this too:

```
DELETE table_name 
FROM table_name 
  JOIN
    ( SELECT id
      FROM table_name
      ORDER BY          --- whatever
      LIMIT 10, 30
    ) AS tmp
    ON tmp.id = table_name.id
```

Comment: I think the reason for "not work" is that the same table is mentioned directly.

Answer (score 0):

When deleting a lot of rows, this is an efficient trick:

```
CREATE TABLE new LIKE real;   -- empty table with same schema
INSERT INTO new SELECT * FROM real ... LIMIT 10;  -- copy the rows to _keep_
RENAME TABLE real TO old, new TO real;  -- rearrange
DROP TABLE old;  -- clean up.
```