# how to delete records in a table in mysql but keep first x records

Tags: php, mysql

I want to write a query in mysql for delete action. I want to keep first X records and for example only delete records after row number 40. I mean I want to keep first x rows and delete all rows after that.
how can I write this query?

I can delete first rows but I don't know how I can delete rows after row number X

I tried this code but this is not correct and not working.

```
DELETE FROM `myTable` WHERE `username` = 'name' ORDER BY `DD` DESC LIMIT 40 OFFSET 3
```

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561446/how-to-delete-every-record-after-the-nth-row-in-mysql

Comment: i checked that and not solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**

```
DELETE FROM `myTable` WHERE `id` in ( select `id` from `myTable` where `username` = 'name' ORDER BY `DD` DESC Limit 40, 18446744073709551615)
```

Comment: the problem is that i have not total number of records i want delete recorde 40 to last

Comment: @MojtabaGS3 , check my edit, this will always delete from 40 to last.

Comment: @MojtabaGS3 can you please try the above

Comment: i get the last number too i mean now i want delete row 40 to 100 ... but any comment i used not worked!

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '70' at line 1 .................... i used 70 for last record number

Answer (score 1):

`LIMIT 40 OFFSET 3` is for PostgreSQL.

For MySql you can try `LIMIT 40,X`

40 = starting at row 40
X = quantity of rows to delete after that

Answer (score 1):

Obligatory Disclaimer: There are no "first rows" intrinsic to a relational database table.

However, since you've provided an `ORDER BY`, something like this should work (maybe):

```
SELECT `DD` INTO @dd40
FROM `myTable` 
WHERE `username` = 'name'
ORDER BY `DD` ASC
LIMIT 39, 1
;
DELETE FROM `myTable` 
WHERE `username` = 'name' 
AND `DD` > @dd40
;
```

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation

#1093 - You can't specify target table 'ofRoster' for update in FROM clause

Comment: @MojtabaGS3 I was half expecting that from the first one, have you tried the second yet? (Removing first since you've confirmed it fails.)

Answer (score 0):

```
delete a
from sales.xxx_log_xxx as a
join ( 
        select b.code,b.up_date
        from sales.xxx_log_xxx as b 
        where b.code = 'code'
        order by b.up_date desc limit 5,50) as aa

on a.code = aa.code
and a.up_date = aa.up_date
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).